# Testing in laravel against MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, testing

Hello i m testing in **laravel 5.5** an api using **Mysql** as database and **DatabaseTransactions**.

Suppose that i have a model `Team` which may be `active` or `inactive` and i want to  test getting an inactive Team.

```
$team = Team::inactive()->inRandomOrder()->first();
$response = $this->json('GET',route('teams.show',$team->id); 
$reponse ->assertStatus(404);
```

This piece of code is problematic if there is no inactive team in my 
fake seeded database.
So what's the best approach here ?

1)Should i make sure i seed database with an inactive team ?
2) Should i  make an assertion after first line and if `$team==null` i make team `inactive` for the purpose of testing .
3)Use factory during tests and create fake data ?

The only reason i avoided 3 for the time being is that in more complex relationships with foreign keys i have to seed 3-4 tables.

Comment: Check out factory states. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#factory-states

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test each case independently if they can realistically happen. If a case can occur where no inactive teams exist, test for that. If no tears can exist at all, write a test for that too.

Running migrations and seeding is quite common before tests. Laravel provides some helpful utilities to do just that as well as roll back during tear down. Keep your tests atomic and isolated from one another as much as possible.

Comment: Of course my tests are isolated.I know there is **RefreshDatabase** but it doesn't behave always as i want .Also using **Transactions**  just allows you to make one **Database Refresh** for all your tests.
The whole point of the question is that there are totally more than 20 cases that may not be found in a common `database seed` i run .For example `banned users`, `users with scopes`, etc...
So either i have to make extra seeds for specific tests or . 
 take advantage of Transactions.Make my model meet the requirements for this tests and just go on

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test. You are not confined to a single database state. Nor should you be opposed to seeding 3-4  tables. Sqlite (or another in memory database )  is quite fast comparatively. Yes, I know you specifically mentioned mysql but what are you really testing then? Your code or your database? When testing code, your means of storage does not matter provided the data returned is the same .

Comment: First of all testing with mysql is not a _bad practise_ .It 's a bit slower  but you  are 100 % sure since you are using your production software
Secondly My tables initially are seeded.Like I said before when you test complex situations you may have so many cases that may not be represented in a random seed even if you seed  before every test.
These cases are not database states ! They are which can happen when someone uses your api !
Example **get a user who is banned**.If i try test this functinality but i have no user in databse who is banned i should create one .So extra seeds required

Comment: I never rely on random seeding to produce all test cases. Look at my other comment regarding factory states. That is a good way to reproduce a specific database state on a per test basis. I've tested a lot of code in a number of industries. Sometimes it takes longer writing the tests than the app itself.

Comment: Ok I got your point.That s what i thought it s the best approach .Just wanted to make sure there is no other way.Because sometimes taking a simple approach might be healthier for your tests to maintain